# Share large files through torrent - deluge

Tags: networking, port, file-sharing, bittorrent, deluge

I am trying to share a large data file (~2.5 Gb) with a colleague using the bittorrent protocol.
I am on `Fedora 30` and I am using `Deluge 1.3.15`.

To create the `torrent` file, I am following the steps seen below on `Deluge`:

1. File ---> Create Torrent
2. I am adding the file (it's a `.zip` file)
3. In the tracker settings I've tried two different things:
4. No trackers at all **or**
5. I added `http://11.111.111.111:PORT/announce`. I took the port number from Edit--->Preferences--->Network--->Active port. (Note that when testing the active port, sometimes it's ok, sometimes it's not and I believe that this might be the issue). Of course I added my own IP address.
6. I created the `.torrent` file and send it to my colleague.

Note that a few days ago I was able to share another file with him following steps 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, therefore without adding any trackers whatsoever.

In addition my colleague is able to ping me using the `ping` command.

I believe that the problem is the port, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Any idea or help would be more than welcome!

Comment: Check if Deluge is not set to use a random port on startup. If so, uncheck the box, select a port, preferably in the TCP 6881~6999 range favored by BT, and include it in your torrent info.

Comment: @Didier Thanks a lot for your comment. I did disable the *random ports* but I still have an issue with my port being not active. https://imgur.com/wtuJqXh I think that's the issue, but I can't prove it

Comment: You used the right port range for incoming traffic, but you're trying to *seed* a file, so you must uncheck the random port for outgoing traffic... The danger sign next to your port range for incoming is strange, though. Try to uncheck random in outgoing and see how it goes regardless.